# Overflow doesn't make flexbox container's children to resize

Tags: css, overflow, flexbox

I've in my layout a footer which has `display: flex; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 100%; align-items: flex-start; justify-content: space-around;`. Inside it there are a undefined number of divs which shall resize according to it's content.

In my tests, I put 3 divs within footer, one of them (3rd one) with a large width content. These divs are getting resized strangely... The 3rd is taking on a piece of 1st and 2nd's width making they having their content broken, see:

[image: Flexbox div screenshot]

`overflow: auto;` doesn't work as expected because just adds a horizontal scrolling.

How can I fix this problem? Why 3rd div has priority resizing to accommodate it's content?

And another thing: as you can see, first red div has as content a list. Strangely only it's first item has a marker. I applied no CSS for that and adding `display: none;` (could be a out of space problem) to 2nd and 3rd divs doesn't fix it. What the what?

Obs: English tips referring to this message are welcome as well. =D

See all this things here: http://jsfiddle.net/T5YSe/

Comment: Could you post a fiddle showing the whole code?

Comment: I've added fiddle to question post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All three of your flex items are shrinking (when there's not enough space to accommodate their collective preferred widths) due to their default `flex-shrink: 1` value.

You can use the `flex` shorthand to fix this -- in particular, you probably want to make the first two flex items `flex: none`, to prevent them from flexing at all (and in particular, from shrinking below their intrinsic width).  However, you probably *do* want the third item to be able to shrink (below the width of its single line of text), so that one probably wants to still have the default `flex: 0 1 auto`.

Fiddle with that fixed (`flex` property added to `footer-column` CSS and to the inline style rule for the third column): http://jsfiddle.net/R3zCk/

(I didn't bother adding prefixed versions of my "flex" shorthands in the fiddle above; you can do that if you like.)

Comment: Many thanks. This almost solves the problem.

I'll see what can I do to use this solution in correct `div`s, as I'm not able to foresee which one will have a large width text as content.

Comment: Get your +1 for `flex: none`.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to dholbert's answer to solve the problem with the flexbox.

As for your list not displaying properly, that's because it's using the tags backwards. It should be written like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ops, how I did let it go unnoticed?
Thanks so much.